Как совместить вывод типов и пользовательские преобразования при передаче объекта в шаблонную функцию
Извиняюсь за путанное название. Не знаю как еще это назвать.
Есть некая обёртка-ссылка
template <typename T>
class my_wrapper {
private:
    T* _ptr;
public:
    my_wrapper(T& arg) : _ptr(std::addressof(arg)) {}
    operator T() { return *_ptr ; }
};

Нужно чтобы при передаче экземпляров этого класса в функцию, они воспринимались как исходный класс, а не как класс-обёртка.
При передаче в обычные функции, всё работает. Компилятор просто берёт подходящее пользовательское преобразование
void foo(int const&) {
    std::cout << "detected int\n";
}

int main() {
    int v1;
    my_wrapper<decltype(v1)> wrap_1(v1);
    foo(wrap_1); // ok

Но я хочу передавать их в шаблонную функции, где не только нужно сделать преобразование, но и вывод типов.
template<typename T>
void foo(std::vector<T> const&) {
    std::cout << "detected std::vector<T> [T = " << typeid(T).name() << "]\n";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v3;
    my_wrapper<decltype(v3)> wrap_3(v3);
    foo(wrap_3); // fail

Вот ссылка, где я оставил свои потуги для посмотреть/покрутить https://godbolt.org/z/MM61EK9er
Это, скажем так, самый минимальный пример, который хотелось бы решить https://godbolt.org/z/orvTqe97x
Но есть одно НО! Я не могу менять целевые функции под свой врапер. Т.е. мне нужно решить проблему именно на стороне врапера. Чтобы он передавал себя как содержимое.
И еще у меня есть большое подозрение, что решить задачу так, как я её ставлю, нельзя в принципе. Правильно ли я подозреваю, что решать её нужно через добавление метода get(), как это сделано в стандартном std::reference_wrapper?

Да, это невозможно сделать.

Максимум можно сделать свое подобие std::invoke которое раскрывает такие обертки.

¿А почему бы не сделать template<typename T> void foo(my_wrapper<T> const&) и внутри вызывать нужную функцию? А вообще это оддает проблемой XY.

@user7860670 да, это я понимаю. Поэтому и пояснил, что нужно решить проблему именно на стороне врапера. Т.е. есть 3 уровня, где я можно что-то сделать: 1. создание функций 2. создание врапера 3. вызов функции/передача врапера в качестве параметра. 1-ый вариант мне не доступен. На 3-ем, действительно получается, что это никак не решить. Остаётся 2-ой вариант. Да, я могу, например, добавить перегрузку для конкретной функции под мой врапер: template<typename T> void foo (my_wrapper<T> const& wrap) { return foo(static_cast<T>(wrap)); } Но это уж совсем как-то мувитон...

Короче, действительно, проще всего добавить враперу 'get' (который по сути и выполняет функцию кастомного приведения типа) и на этапе 2 вместо врапера передавать этот get в качестве аргумента. А точнее, проще либо воспользоваться потомком от std::reference_wrapper либо вообще исключить обработку случаем, когда оборачиваемый объект - это ссылка, и оставить это на откуп пользователю. Вот откуда это, если интересно https://godbolt.org/z/c9b8bhq63 Осталось только с массивами разобраться. Это просто баловство, не реальный проект, если что.
